# Chain rule notation for function with two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Define $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$. I want to show that $f$ has partial derivatives in both variables.

So I should be using the chain rule here. I want to look at $\dfrac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial{x}}$, which is equal to $\dfrac{\partial{g(x+y)}}{\partial{x}}$, and by the chain rule this is $\dfrac{d{g(x+y)}}{d{(x+y)}}\cdot \dfrac{d{(x+y)}}{d{x}}$. The first term exists because $g$ is differentiable, and the second term is just $1$, since we hold $y$ constant when differentiating by $x$.

Is this a correct reasoning using the chain rule? While doing this, I'm also confused about notation. When should I use $d$ and when should I use $\partial$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would write my computation of $f$'s partial derivatives:

Denote by $p_a$ the function $p_a(b) = a+b$. Then we have

$${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x} = {\partial g(p_y(x)) \over \partial x} = (g \circ p_y)'(x) = g'(p_y(x)) \cdot p_y'(x) = g'(x+y)$$

and similarly we get that $\displaystyle {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y} = g'(x+y)$ — which should be obvious due to the symmetry between $x$ and $y$ in the definition of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your $\dfrac{\partial g(p_y(x))}{\partial x}$, do you think the $\partial$ sign is appropriate? Because in a way, here we're thinking of $y$ as fixed, so $g$ is only a function of one variable, $x$.

Comment: It honestly doesn't matter. The partial derivative of a single-variable function is just the ordinary derivative.